# GooglePlacesAutocomplete react native show only cities in result

Tags: react-native, google-places-autocomplete

How can i show only cities in the results of react-native-google-places-autocomplete?

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      filterReverseGeocodingByTypes = {['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3']}
      placeholder={noLocation ? i18n.translate("noLocationAdded")  : i18n.translate("searchLocation") }
      placeholderTextColor={"red"}
      minLength={2} 
      autoFocus={true}
      returnKeyType={'search'} 
      listViewDisplayed={false} 
      fetchDetails={true}
      textInputProps={{
        placeholderTextColor: noLocation ? 'red' : colors.lightGray,
        returnKeyType: "search",
        value: value ,
        onChangeText: text => {
          console.log("inputing in google autocomplete")
          console.log(text)
          if (text.length === 0) {
            setLocation(text);
          }
          setLocation(text);
        },
      }}

      onPress={async (data, details = null) => {
          let latitude = details.geometry.location.lat
        let longitude = details.geometry.location.lng
        let coordObj = {latitude, longitude}
        const address = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(coordObj);
        let city = address[0].city
        setLocation(data.description);
        setCity(city);
      }}
      query={{
        key: "AIz____________________________________",
        language: "en",
      }}
      nearbyPlacesAPI="GooglePlacesSearch"
      debounce={300}
    />
```

I want to show only cities from a specific country when the user enters a text in the search box.

I've tried with filterReverseGeocodingByTypes = {['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3']}

Answer (score 0):

In Google Place Autocomplete, you can [restrict results to 1 or more (up to 5) countries](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#components).

There is an example in https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-places-autocomplete to **Limit results to one country**, adding it to the `query` like this:

```
query={{
  ...
  components: 'country:us',
}}
```

BTW please make sure to [**restrict your API keys**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/get-api-key#restrict_key) (also, avoid exposing your API keys unnecessarily, like here).